# Media Queries are affecting the desktop version, but not the mobile version

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I have a css media query but it seems to be mixed up and I'm not sure why. It's making the desktop version look like what I want the mobile version to be, and the mobile version looks like what I want the desktop to be. Here is the css page in question:

```css
@media (min-width: 500px;) {
    body{background-image:url(ollivanderbackground.jpg);color:#FFFF66;}
    .navigation{color:#FFFF99; border:dotted medium #FFFF99; width: 35%;}
    a:hover{color: #FFFFCC;} 
    a:visited{color: #FFFF1A;}  
} 
@media (max-width: 499px;) {
    .navigation{width: 100%;}
    .bio{display: none;}    
}
```

in the HTML for the page I have this within the head tags:

```
<'meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"'>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the semicolon from your media queries ... `@media (max-width: 499px) { ... }`

Comment: I will vote to close this question because it is a simple typographical error.

Comment: @Ricky I removed the media (max-width: 499px;){ } around the second declarations of styles but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Remove the `;` semicolons, not the media query itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It turns out My browser history was really clogged and was loading an older version of the site while trying to mix it with the new CSS and things got really mixed up and weird.

Clearing my browser data fixed this problem. Thanks to all for your helpful tries!

Answer (score 0):

you can try use '@media screen'

```
@media screen and (min-width:200px) and (max-width:1000px)
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more detail

Comment: try as this style @media screen and (min-width:200px) and (max-width:1000px)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
@media (min-width: 500px;) { ... } 
@media (max-width: 499px;) { ... }
```

To:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) { ... } 
@media (max-width: 499px) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the semi-colon should have fixed the issue

```
@media (min-width: 500px) { ... }
@media (max-width: 499px) { ... }
```

Since that is not working, try adding screen

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) { ... }
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) { ... }
```

If that does not resolve your issue, then add a snippet with your question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, and I am going out on a limb here without seeing the rest of your code, your responsive layouts are being messed up possibly due to a bad or missing declaration of viewport.

Check, replace, or add this in your head. You currently have single quotes around it

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Read more about it [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Also, build your application with a mobile-first approach

media max = 480 --> do this until

media max = 768 --> if changes required change or continue to

media max = 989 --> if changes required change or continue to

media max = 1200